# Mongoose error whenever running node app.js

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Whenever I try to run node app.js, it always ends up showing problem in the pre-built mongoose library.It shows error like this : at D:\todolist-v2-starting-files\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3159:47

and the 3159:47 line goes like this :

```
for (let i = 0; i < error.writeErrors.length; ++i) {
          const originalIndex = validDocIndexToOriginalIndex.get(error.writeErrors[i].index);
          error.writeErrors[i] = {
            ...error.writeErrors[i],
            index: originalIndex
          };
          if (!ordered) {
            results[originalIndex] = error.writeErrors[i];
          }
        }
```

What should I do to make it work. I ran mongod before running node app.js still It always ends up showing this error.

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: Specify your error. This question is very vague and not informative.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the error clearly maybe posting a screenshot would have helped, but maybe try ***npm i mongoose*** again go to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/ and read the related document for importing mongoose it can help, as with mongoose 7 there are a lot of changes in the module, hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).